# Exporting/importing in node.js / discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am currently making a discord bot with discord.js and because I haven't programmed without an html file before I find using several js-files quite difficult. At first i thought using imports and exports was gonna work, but it isn't supported in Node yet. I did some snooping around and this is what i decided to do:

#### Index.js

```
const commandFunctions = require('./commands.js')();
const botconfig = require('./botconfig.json');

bot.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) { return; }
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') { return; }

    messageArray = message.content.split(' ');
    cmd = messageArray[0];
    arg = messageArray.slice(1);

    if (cmd.charAt(0) === prefix) {
        checkCommands(message);
    } else {
        checkForWord(message);
    }
});

function checkCommands(message) {
    botconfig.commands.forEach(command => {
        if (arg === command) {
            commandFunctions.ping();
        }
    });
}
```

#### commands.js

```
module.exports = function() {
    this.botinfo = function(message, bot) {
        let bicon = bot.user.displayAvatarURL;
        let botembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor('#DE8D9C')
        .setThumbnail(bicon)
        .addField('Bot Name', bot.user.username)
        .addField('Description', 'Inject the memes into my bloodstream')
        .addField('Created On', bot.user.createdAt.toDateString());
        return message.channel.send(botembed);
    } 

    this.roll = function(message) {
        let roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        return message.channel.send(`${message.author.username} rolled a ${roll}`);
    }

    this.ping = function() {
        return message.channel.send('pong');
    }
}
```

#### botconfig.json

```
"prefix": "+",
"commands": [
     "botinfo",
     "roll",
     "ping"
]
```

My goal would be to make the code adaptable by just having to add a word to the json-file and a function that is connected to it in the commands.js. In the checkCommand function it should also trigger the function with the same name as the command, right now i've set it to trigger ping no matter what command I use, as I had some trouble with the arguments. Problem is the command-function is not being triggered at all, pretty sure that the checkCommand function is where it goes wrong.

Comment: what?? they are supported... you're literally using them in the code given, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `this` pointing to the returned object inside a function you have to call it using the `new` operator:

```
 const commandFunctions = new require('./commands.js')();
```

However that is quite counterintuitive, so you migut just export an object from "commands.js":

```
module.exports = {
  ping: function() { /*...*/ }
  //...
};
```

Which then can be imported easily:

```
const commandFunctions = require('./commands.js');
commandFunctions.ping();
```

---

To execute the commands, you don't need to load the json, just check if the property exists in the commands object,:

```
 const commands = require('./commands.js');

 function execCommand(command) {
   if(commands[command]) {
     commands[command]();
  } else {
     commands.fail();
 }
}
```

---

PS: globals (`cmd`, `arg`) are a very very bad idea, instead you should pass the values as arguments.

Comment: That fixed my first problem, but now I get the error 'cannot read property "channel" of undefined' even though i pass the message through as an argument.

Comment: @dubster you have to pass it here `commands[command](whatever);`, but thats hard to tell without code.

Comment: I am doing that, passing through message and the bot in that order, then i added message in the command.ping() function.

Comment: Nevermind, I don't know what the problem was, but I managed to resolve it somehow, maybe a typo. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @dubster glad to help :)